# Identity managment on Ethereum Blockchain for e voting system

Tags: dapps

I'm writing proposal for my final year project. The title is E-voting system using Ethereum Blockchain. There is a problem i don't know how to address. What if i want to use data to authorize voter from some of the government database. How to implement this on Ethereum or i have to go with Hyper-ledger fabrics.Can't find any such implementation on github though.

Answer (score 0):

It's an interesting project, but has certain challenges. At least:

- How do you know which Ethereum address is for which government database entry
- How do you get data from some government database
- Once an address has been associated to an identity, how do you prevent selling the address and whatnot other abuse
- What happens if user loses access to the addres

And lots of similar types of issues.

On-chain identity is not a trivial feat. I don't know how using another blockchain solution would make it easier.